# How can I have a counter like transition for a button label with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button and I want to change its label from say 1 to 2, so that 1 slides up and meanwhile 2 replaces it. It's what I tried in the snippet. However, nothing is shown in the end. Please note that 1 and 2 are examples, in general it should replaces the old value with a new value on an event.

```js
$('#slideIndexBox').slideDown().promise().done(function() {
  $(this).text('2');
  $(this).slideUp();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="indicator" class="btn mb-2 btn-block btn-outline-info ">
  <!--<span id="slideIndicator"></span>-->
  <span id="slideIndexBox">1</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the effect you're going for, I would add a new element each time the number is incremented. These numbers could be added to a container, and with each click, the container would slide up to reveal the newly-appended element.

It would look something like this:

```js
$("#indicator").click(function() {
  let number = $(".slideIndexBox", this).length + 1;
  let $num = $("<span class='slideIndexBox' />");
  $num.text(number);
  
  let $container = $(".slideContainer", this);
  let height = Math.round($(this).css("height").replace("px",""));
  $container
    .append($num)
    .css("transform", `translateY(-${(number-1)*height}px)`);
});
```

```css
button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.slideIndexBox {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(6px);
}

.slideContainer {
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="indicator" class="btn mb-2 btn-block btn-outline-info ">
  <span class="slideContainer">
    <span class="slideIndexBox">1</span>
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great, however could you please improve it so that if new number is greater than the previous number slides up, otherwise slides down

Comment: @Ahmad Your example includes no description of the logic of determining the next number; I was under the impression it was just an incrementing counter. I feel like I've provided enough of an answer that you should at the very least be able to expand it to handle such a condition :)

Comment: @Ahmad I can work on it in a little while, unfortunately I don't currently have the chance to edit it.

Comment: I tried your code before this edit (the new edit didn't work) and that woks as charm! It actually does what I want without any change!!! just after it was filled with children to the total number of slides.

Answer (score 2):

Please try it:

```html
<button>
  <label class="show">1</label>
  <label class="hide">2</label>
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('button').on( 'click', function() {
    $(this).find('.hide').slideDown();
    $(this).find('.show').slideUp();
});
</script>

<style>
.show { display: block; }
.hide { display: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: You can create a running snippet on SO, [`Read here`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Thanks, but still couldn't apply it. 1 and 2 are examples, in general it should replaces the old value with a new value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but it will scroll back to the top after the last one. In this case below I've just added all the items right from the start since it will give your button an accurate width. You can just add items as you go however you like but the button will change width in that case.

This solution will however require that your button text is on one line to work. Also the button height is just arbitrary in the css.

```js
$('#indicator').on('click', function () {
  var $container = $('div', this),
    index = ($container.data('i') || 0) + 1;
  if (index + 1 > $('span', $container).length) {
    $container.data('i', 0);
    $container.css('transform', 'translateY(0)');
  } else {
    $container.data('i', index);
    $container.css('transform', 'translateY(' + -$('span', this).height() * index + 'px)');
  }
});
```

```css
.btn { height: 1.5em; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; }
.btn span {
  display: block;
}
.btn div {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="indicator" class="btn mb-2 btn-block btn-outline-info ">
  <div>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>Moar content</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

I see you need to replace the value though so this might not be what you are looking for.